# Resize electron window from bottom-left to top-right?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, electron, desktop-application

So I'm working on an electron app where I'm showing a circular shaped camera bubble on bottom left of the screen. This window is draggable and resizable(by clicking on the 1 of 3 sizes avaiable)

Now when some user tries to resize the window I follow this step -

- `setBounds({x,y,widht, height})`
  or
- `setPosition() first then setContentSize()`

Now the issue is the window is resized properly and the position is also set properly but their is this weird animation/flash when the position of window changes.

Can someone point me in the right direction to resize the window in such a way that to a user it appears resizing from bottom left to top right like shown in this diagram below?

[image]